# Progress Bar mientras se genera un archivo en Excel

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excel, datagridview, progressbar

Me gustaria implementar un progress bar en mi aplicacion que indique el porcentaje de progreso mientra se genera un archivo en Excel con los datos de un datagridview pero no estoy muy familiarizado como se usa y donde lo debo usar en mi codigo, estoy usando el lenguaje de c# que lineas de codigo debo poner para usar el progress bar? aqui esta una demostracion de mi codigo espero puedan ayudarme

```
//Metodo de excel
    private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
    {
        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabaj
            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewCell celda in grd.Rows[i].Cells)
                {
                    if ((grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "Id") == (grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "tipoPriority") == (grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "Seleccionar"))
                    {
                        if (celda.Value != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = celda.Value?.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = null;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
             libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);

            aplicacion.Quit();
          //  Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;//cambia el tipo de cursor al tipo wait
          //  Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;//restaura el tipo de cursor de defecto
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: que lineas de codigo debo poner para usar el progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
{
    SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
    fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
    if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
        aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
        hoja_trabajo =
            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabaj
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = grd.Rows.Count;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            progressBar1.Value = (i+1);
            foreach (DataGridViewCell celda in grd.Rows[i].Cells)
            {
                if ((grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "Id") == (grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "tipoPriority") == (grd.Columns[celda.ColumnIndex].Name != "Seleccionar"))
                {
                    if (celda.Value != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = celda.Value?.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = null;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
         libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
        libros_trabajo.Close(true);

        aplicacion.Quit();
      //  Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;//cambia el tipo de cursor al tipo wait
      //  Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;//restaura el tipo de cursor de defecto
    }
}
```